# Wrapping text around adsense ad for my website for mobile screens having widths under 320px

Tags: google-adsense, mobile, content, google-adsense-policies

The attached picture is a picture of my web browser resized to a 240 pixel width so that I can emulate my phone.

Adsense seems to like it when I wrap text (aka what they call "content") around the ad, but this screenshot is giving me grief because I can't seem to fit the word "Entertainment" to the right of the ad unit. The ad size here is 160px wide by 320px long. Also, there is a gap in the flow of text. These issues don't happen if I make the screen width larger than 240 pixels.

I'm going against responsive ads since I like to experiment and learn what works best for the users.

I could attempt using a 160px by 600px ad unit since that unit scored me good revenue back in the day.

I have a couple of options but I don't know which one is best for both users, all devices, and google adsense team.

I can either:

1. choose a font family that allows letters to be more crammed together in hopes I can fit the word "Entertainment" to the right of the ad unit. Currently, I'm using Arial, but I don't know which is the best font to use given my situation,

OR

2. reduce the font size so the word "Entertainment" fits nicely and pray users can still see the text,

OR

3. Apply CSS rules so that some words (such as "Entertainment") can break so part of the word fits on the end of one line and the other part begin on the next line.

Considering adsense cares more about the text content on my page more than my entire client base does, I'm considering going for option 3, but I'm curious if that would be ok with adsense, or if the adsense bot will believe that fractions of words are whole words on my site.

In terms of following adsense policies and making my website compatible with all mobile smartphones, which of my 3 options is the best to use?

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there are many (or any?) mobile phones with device width of 240px or less so you shouldn't worry too much.

Also, why don't you use responsive ad unit and dictate size of the ad unit for each screen size.

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display:inline-block; width: 120px; height: 600px; }
@media (max-width: 280px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
@media (min-width:400px) { .adslot_1 { width: 160px; height: 600px; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 336px; height: 280px; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
   data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

The above code will show the ad for devices like this -

- Less than 280px device - No advertisement (or you can display
  120x600px ad here as well)
- For 280-400px devices -  120x600 ad
- For 400-800px devices - 160x600 ad
- For device above 800px - 336x280 ad

You can read more about [modifying adsense code here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124).